# "Trouble with Python Requests Library: Unable to Authenticate with API"

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to make API requests using the requests library in Python, but I'm encountering authentication issues. I've followed the documentation and provided the necessary credentials, but I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized error. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.example.com/data"
api_key = "my_api_key"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

I've double-checked my API key, and it seems correct. Are there any common pitfalls or additional steps I might be missing when working with the requests library for API authentication in Python? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

Verified that the API key is correct and has the necessary permissions.
Checked the API documentation to ensure I'm using the correct endpoint and headers.

Tested the API request using a tool like cURL, and it worked as expected.
Despite these efforts, I still receive a 401 Unauthorized error when making the request in Python using the requests library. I expected the code to successfully authenticate with the API and return the desired data.

I'm looking for insights into any potential mistakes in my code, suggestions for debugging authentication issues with the requests library, or additional steps I might take to identify and resolve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!